# Opencart 2 admin api calls when in maintenance mode

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

When I put my site into maintenance mode and try to use the order history from admin I get:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

How can I pass the authentication data in the curl request so the maintenance mode is disabled if logged in as admin?

```
public function api() {
    $json = array();

    // Store
    if (isset($this->request->get['store_id'])) {
        $store_id = $this->request->get['store_id'];
    } else {
        $store_id = 0;
    }

    $this->load->model('setting/store');

    $store_info = $this->model_setting_store->getStore($store_id);

    if ($store_info) {
        $url = $store_info['ssl'];
    } else {
        $url = HTTPS_CATALOG;
    }

    if (isset($this->session->data['cookie']) && isset($this->request->get['api'])) {
        // Include any URL perameters
        $url_data = array();

        foreach ($this->request->get as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 'route' && $key != 'token' && $key != 'store_id') {
                $url_data[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        $curl = curl_init();

        // Set SSL if required
        if (substr($url, 0, 5) == 'https') {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
        }

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url . 'index.php?route=' . $this->request->get['api'] . ($url_data ? '&' . http_build_query($url_data) : ''));

        if ($this->request->post) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($this->request->post));
        }

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . $this->session->data['cookie'] . ';');

        $json = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
    }

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput($json);
}
```

I noticed in the other methods they are this extra request for api/login. Is there a way I can merge the 2 together

```
$api_info = $this->model_user_api->getApi($this->config->get('config_api_id'));

if ($api_info) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    // Set SSL if required
    if (substr(HTTPS_CATALOG, 0, 5) == 'https') {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, HTTPS_CATALOG . 'index.php?route=api/login');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($api_info));

    $json = curl_exec($curl);

    if (!$json) {
        $this->error['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_curl'), curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));
    } else {
        $response = json_decode($json, true);

        if (isset($response['cookie'])) {
            $this->session->data['cookie'] = $response['cookie'];
        }

        curl_close($curl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that's been noted a few times in the github issue list for OpenCart. This hasn't been fixed yet, but [this commit](https://github.com/JAY6390/opencart/commit/99cc5a7e0aebbad291c1077569df857c259e4a4f) shows what you need to do to get this working

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/pull/2606) but it seems all pull requests are being ignored

Comment: Yep, I had the same feeling thus stopped supporting the project at all. I wanted to support the 2.0 RC but all pull request were ignored, declined or they made some changes so that the requests had no sense in the end... To be honest I'm little bit disappointed about the whole project and 2.0 update... Maybe I was expecting more from them.